# private discord bot announcer not sending due to math?

Tags: python, discord.py

I own 2 open servers available to the public, due to that I have 2 private staff servers I need to get announcements out quick! Whole point of the bot is to do `.announce (message)` command and it will send to all the
people in the private servers. However it won't work, I dont' know if it had to do with my math equations. Not sure if it is `+= x` or `= +x`. It may also be the `if not member.bot`, I'm not really sure what I was doing.

````
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

token = 'token'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Watching Your Moderation", url='https://www.twitch.tv/discord'))
    print('online')
        
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if hasattr(ctx.command, "on_error"):
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        return


@client.command()
async def announce(ctx, *, content):
    if ctx.author.id == ownerid:
        await ctx.send("Starting messaging.")
        not_sent = 0
        total_messaged = 0
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                if not member.bot:
                    try:
                        await member.send(content)
                        total_messaged = +1
                    except discord.HTTPException:
                        not_sent = +1
        await ctx.send(f"{total_messaged} have been messaged. {not_sent} have not been messaged (not enough permissions).")

client.run(token)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the assignment of your variables

```
variable = +1
```

Does not increment its value, but only **sets** its value to `+1`, which is basically equal to `1`

---

To increment a variable (what you want in this case) is using

```
variable += 1
```

This is equivalent to saying

```
variable = variable + 1
```

---

Your `if not member.bot` is correct. You're checking, if `member.bot` is set to `False`.

Your real problem however is that your are 100% being rate-limited, or worst case banned by Discords anti-spam system.
If you try to DM a lot of Discord users, their system **will** flag you, and your bot **will** get banned from using parts of the API!!!
To prevent this, use a delay between your messages.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio

token = 'token'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name="Watching Your Moderation", url='https://www.twitch.tv/discord'))
    print('online')
        
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if hasattr(ctx.command, "on_error"):
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        return


@client.command()
async def announce(ctx, *, content):
    if ctx.author.id == ownerid:
        await ctx.send("Starting messaging.")
        not_sent = 0
        total_messaged = 0
        for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                if not member.bot:
                    try:
                        await member.send(content)
                        total_messaged += 1
                        await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    except discord.HTTPException:
                        not_sent += 1
        await ctx.send(f"{total_messaged} have been messaged. {not_sent} have not been messaged (not enough permissions).")

client.run(token)
```

Comment: `discord.py` should handle rate limits already

Comment: Yeah you're right, it does. But still, mass DM users will still get you banned by Discord anti-spam system. I already was... because I didn't use delays... Maybe "rate-limiting" is not perfectly correct here... yet it still states whats happeing ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @itzFlubby
thanks for the reply, i did have the += before and thought it looked strange and flipped it to = + so that didnt help.
for the delay, how would i add that since i have 2 servers instead of 1

Comment: You don't need a different implementation for that. The one in my answer will work fine with in fact any amount of guilds. Once all members of one guild will have been notified, your code will start notifing all members of the next guild. It often helps to just express what your code does. `for guild in client.guild` -> for every guild the bot is in do `for member in guild.members` -> for every member in every guild the bot is in. This includes what you're asking for :)

Comment: Being banned for spamming is different to being banned for exceeding rate limits (if that is even a bannable offence and not just being time outed). Discord probably picked up that the account was sending DMs to multiple users, which it flagged as spam. If you use `discord.py` you shouldn't have to worry about rate limits as the library already takes care of it for you.